# What does this result of Limit mean?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

In version 13.0.1 on Windows 10:

```
Limit[E^(-2 a \[Pi])*Gamma[(I a)/2 - n] ((4^-n E^((3 a \[Pi])/2 + I n \[Pi]) \[Pi])/(
Gamma[-2 n] Gamma[1 + (I a)/2 + n]) + 
I (-1 + E^(2 a \[Pi])) *Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, 
1 + (I a)/2 + n, 1 + (I a)/2 - n, -1]), {a, n} -> {2*I, 4}, Direction -> Complexes]
```

> `` If[Complexes == Reals, 
>  Asymptotics`MultivariateLimitDump`ff$1612446 = 
>   Asymptotics`MultivariateLimitDump`realfpreproc[
>    Asymptotics`MultivariateLimitDump`ff$1612446, {a, n}, 
>    Asymptotics`MultivariateLimitDump`zero$1612446]; 
>  Asymptotics`MultivariateLimitDump`RealMLimit[
>   Asymptotics`MultivariateLimitDump`ff$1612446, {a, n}, 
>   Asymptotics`MultivariateLimitDump`zero$1612446, {Limit, True, False, Complexes, 
>    Automatic, Automatic, "Quality"}], 
>  Asymptotics`MultivariateLimitDump`ComplexMLimit[
>   Asymptotics`MultivariateLimitDump`ff$1612446, {a, n}, 
>   Asymptotics`MultivariateLimitDump`zero$1612446, {Limit, True, False, Complexes, 
>    Automatic, Automatic, "Quality"}]] ``

This is not the returned input. The expression under the limit originates from `Integrate[E^(-a*x)*(Cos[x]^2)^n, {x, 0, 2*Pi},  Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers,  GenerateConditions -> True]`.

Comment: The same issue with `Limit[1/2 E^(-2 a \[Pi] - 
    I n \[Pi]) (1 + E^(
     a \[Pi])) (1/(a + 2 I n)
       4 (-1 + E^(a \[Pi])) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + (I a)/2 + n, 
       1 + (I a)/2 - n, -1] (Cos[n \[Pi]] + I Sin[n \[Pi]]) + (
     4^-n E^((a \[Pi])/
      2) \[Pi] Gamma[(I a)/2 - n] (1 + I Tan[n \[Pi]]))/(
     Gamma[-2 n] Gamma[1 + (I a)/2 + n]), {a, n} -> {2*I, 4}, 
    Direction -> Complexes]` though the expression under the limit as the result of `Integrate[E^(-a*x)*(Cos[x]^2)^n, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, Assumptions -> n >= 1, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]` should be continuous.

Comment: Moreover, the same issue with `Limit[Evaluate[Integrate[E^(-a*x)*(Cos[x]^2)^n, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> Re[n] >= 1, GenerateConditions -> True]], {n, a} -> {2, 2*I}, Direction -> Complexes]` though the result should be analytical around $(2,2i)$.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a piece of internal code with a rather obvious bug: "==" instead of "===" is used to compare domains, and hence we get an unevaluated If conditional instead of the result of running the "else" case. Will be fixed in the next version of Mathematica. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you. I will be waiting for that version of Mathematica before making a decision.

Comment: It now returns unevaluated after a long timeout (checked the last one in comments). BTW, is there some app (Maple, fricas?) that can do it? Seriously asking.